# Вопросы Олимпиады

Tags: олимпиада

Сижу решаю олимпиаду на время, нашлась задачка не по зубам. В задаче используются элементы NoCode
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цель задачи - съесть фиолетовый кубик. Слева находятся элементы движения (по порядку): Идти в перёд, поворот (лево\право), F1: цикл. А цвет левее них это как бы проверка, если я поставлю этот цвет на движение в перёд (Это пример) то он будет идти в перёд только на красном цвете. Там доступны цвета: синий, красный, зелёный. Я нашёл уже действия которые обязательно нужны там:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не понимаю: что нужно поставить\поменять так что бы это всё работало. Заранее спасибо!
У меня всего 40 минут:(

Comment: http://olympiad.balatech.asia/engine/?level_id=5fa604f7e32aa2780a87b62b, это ссылка на движок который я указал в вопросе

Comment: F1 тоже можно красить =)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что олимпиады нужно решать самостоятельно. Это просто нечестно по отношению к другим участникам.